# XFRM_SUB_POLICY config in kerne

Tags: linux-kernel, ipsec

When testing strongswan performance, we saw that the performance differed by a lot between an ubuntu server and a centos server, with everything else being the same. We noticed that the CONFIG_XFRM_SUB_POLICY settings on the two kernels were different. Ubuntu had it disabled and centos had it enabled. We disabled this on the kernel we built and got the same performance as ubuntu server. Does anyone know when this config is required? Why would one distro have it enabled while the other doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

As I know this is an experimental feature.

`CONFIG_XFRM_SUB_POLICY`:

> Support sub policy for developers. By using sub policy with main
>   one, two policies can be applied to the same packet at once.
>   Policy which lives shorter time in kernel should be a sub.

This is excerpt from the book [Linux Kernel Networking](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143026196X):

> type: Usually the type is XFRM_POLICY_TYPE_MAIN (0). When the kernel has support for
>   subpolicy (CONFIG_XFRM_SUB_POLICY is set), two policies can be applied to the same
>   packet, and you can use the XFRM_POLICY_TYPE_SUB (1) type. Policy that lives a shorter
>   time in kernel should be a subpolicy. This feature is usually needed only for developers/
>   debugging and for mobile IPv6, because you might apply one policy for IPsec and one for
>   mobile IPv6. The IPsec policy is usually the main policy with a longer lifetime than the mobile
>   IPv6 (sub) policy.

I don't know why it is disabled in `Ubuntu` kernel and enabled in `CentOS` kernel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We just disabled the flag and we are back to expected performance. I guess we will leave this disabled for now. Thanx.